# Массивы PHP и ссылки - какая-то магия

Tags: массивы, php

Вот это работает(я не знаю почему):

```
$a = array('a' => 1)
$a['a'] = &$a['b'];
```

При этом в $a['b'] записывается то ли ссылка на `$a['a']`, то ли само `$a['a']` о_О Стоит убрать амперсанд - все, ошибка не объявленного индекса `b`.

Это почему так?

Comment: На самом деле в `$a` храниться ссылка на `NULL` ([`ideone.com`][1]), а когда вы убираете амперсанд, интерпретатор пытается обратиться к ячейке, которой не существует, отсюда и ошибки. 

[1]: http://ideone.com/NCb9AW

Comment: В более развернутом примере там хранились не нуллы о_О

Comment: @Arc, &$a['b'] - это ссылка на элемент b в массиве а. Элемента b у вас же не существует.